# Outgoing email marked as spam: BAYES_99

Tags: email, spam, spamassassin

I am developing a web application. 
All outgoing emails are marked as spam, or totally rejected by receivers' email providers.
This prevents us from sending welcome emails, activation codes, or anything else to registered users.

I tested my email sending with isnotspam.com, and the problem seems to be the BAYES_99 and BAYES_999 metrics. This happens regardless of email content.

Can someone tell me why this is happening?
Is there a way to make outgoing emails not marked as spam by spam filters?

Here the outcome of a isnotspam.com test result (I modified a few parameters for privacy ).

```
    This message is an automatic response from isNOTspam's authentication verifier service. The service allows email senders to perform a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms. It is provided free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community. While it is not officially supported, we welcome any feedback you may have at .

    Thank you for using isNOTspam.

    The isNOTspam team

    ==========================================================
    Summary of Results
    ==========================================================

    SPF Check : pass
    Sender-ID Check : pass
    DomainKeys Check : neutral
    DKIM Check : pass
    SpamAssassin Check : ham (non-spam)
    ==========================================================
    Details:
    ==========================================================

    HELO hostname: my.hostname.com
    Source IP: XX.YY.WW.ZZ
    mail-from: service@mydomain.com
    Anonymous To: ins-3mqqpdgw@isnotspam.com
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    SPF check details:
    ----------------------------------------------------------

    Result: pass
    ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=service@mydomain.com
    DNS record(s):
    mydomain.com.    11379   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:XX.YY.WW.ZZ +ip4:AA.BB.CC.DD +include:_spf.google.com ~all"


    ----------------------------------------------------------
    Sender-ID check details:
    ----------------------------------------------------------

    Result: pass

    ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=service@mydomain.com
    DNS record(s):
    mydomain.com.    11379   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:XX.YY.WW.ZZ +ip4:AA.BB.CC.DD +include:_spf.google.com ~all"


    ----------------------------------------------------------
    DomainKeys check details:
    ----------------------------------------------------------

    Result: neutral (message not signed)
    ID(s) verified: header.From=service@mydomain.com
    Selector=
    domain=
    DomainKeys DNS Record=

    ----------------------------------------------------------
    DKIM check details:
    ----------------------------------------------------------

    Result: pass
    ID(s) verified: header.From=service@mydomain.com
    Selector=default
    domain=mydomain.com

    DomainKeys DNS Record=default._domainkey.mydomain.com


    ----------------------------------------------------------
    SpamAssassin check details:
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28)

    Result: ham (non-spam) (03.7points, 10.0 required)

    pts rule name description
    ---- ---------------------- -------------------------------


    * 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
    * [score: 1.0000]
    * 0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
    * See http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
    * for more information.
    * [URIs: mydomain.com]
    * -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS SPF: HELO matches SPF record
    * -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
    * 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
    * [score: 1.0000]
    * 0.1 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
    * domain
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
    * 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
    * valid
    X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=3.7 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
    DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,
    URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.1
    X-Spam-Score: 3.7
```

Comment: Check the actual response. Chances are the server is reporting as one domain and your email is another. Example: My server's IP address is 1.2.3.4. I send an email from it claiming to be "me@here.com". The receiver checks 1.2.3.4 and it comes up as someserver.com, not here.com. That is one hit against you. Then, it checks here.com and finds that the IP is 10.20.30.40, not 1.2.3.4. That is another hit against you. At this point, it will likely be marked as spam without looking at the content.

Answer (score 2):

I posted this question in total panic, our company was having trouble while launching a new product, customers were dissatisfied and we were struggling finding what the problem was.

In the end, our emails were not received not because of spam detection, but because of an error in our server configuration. There were conditions that caused emails to not be sent at all.

Key takeaway from this story is: if you have problems sending emails, verify that you are sending valid html (through [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org) for example) and check your server configuration before thinking about spam.

Comment: What did the problem turn out to be? I'm struggling with the same issue, although all other metrics (DKIM etc.) are positive and mail-tester.com gives me 10/10.

Comment: The problem was that for some of our customers we were also providing email account (something@mydomain.com), and these email accounts were considered as local, even if they were not. This caused the server to try to send emails to localhost rather than to the correct ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Its statistical method to find a spam in spamassassin i'm not statistic man but you can find your response with the documentation official of spamassassin
and this reponse : [How SpamAssassin defines BAYES_99 ? How to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786009/how-spamassassin-defines-bayes-99-how-to-avoid-it)

https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/BAYES_99

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering